# Getting a value out of an objects dictionary with a key that includes a "-"

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I'm new to JavaScript and im having a problem with getting a value out of an objects dictionary.

As an example lets say my goal is to get the value of the key "Age", which is in a given dictionary like this:

```
{Family : {Smith : {'Max-Martin' : {Age : {_value: '13'}}}}}
```

Usually I would get it with

```
var Max-Martins_age = object.Family.Smith.Max-Martin.Age._value;
```

But the "-" in the key "Max-Martin" results in the error that "Martin is not defined".

Is there a way to call ...Smith.Max-Martin.Age... with telling JavaScript that the "-" is just a char?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, as you've found, a `-` character is not allowed in a variable-name (since it's a mathematical operator), you instead have to use bracket-notation, rather than dot notation, to access Object properties; which means your:

```
var Max-Martins_age = object.Family.Smith.Max-Martin.Age._value;
```

must be written as:

```
var Max-Martins_age = object.Family.Smith["Max-Martin"].Age._value;
```

This accesses the `Max-Martin` property of the `object.Family.Smith` Object, by quoting the String of `"Max-Martin"`.